# Binding values to ASP.NET Chart control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, charts, arraylist, enumeration

I am trying to bind some values to an ASP.NET Chart control. This is my code so far:

```
Dim xValues As String() = {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4"}    
chartControl.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(xValues, valuesAl)
```

`valuesAl` is an `ArrayList`. The code to add the values to the `ArrayList` is as follows:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", Conn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Dim valuesAl As New ArrayList

Dim r As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While r.Read()
    valuesAl.Add(r("Value"))
End While
r.Close()
```

However, I am getting the following error: `Enumeration already finished`

Am I binding the values from the database to the Chart control correctly and if so why am I getting this error message?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are there definitely 4 values in your ArrayList?

Comment: Oops you're right! Why did I not see that?! Thanks very much. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `valuesA1` ArrayList ends up with the same number of values as you have in your `xValues` array. Internally it's looping through both collections, expecting them to have the same number, and you are getting an error because you have fewer members in the valuesA1 ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list value counts are the same and you want the coordinates for the same index value for each list, you can use `series.Points.AddXY()`, for example something like;

```
foreach(int i=0 ; i<valuesAl.Count; i++)
{
    series.Points.AddXY(xValue[i],valuesAl[i];
}
```